# AngularFireAuth - Getting OAuth AccessToken and Persisting

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I'm trying to get Firebase authentication working with AngularFireAuth against Microsoft Oauth.

The login bit is fine.

However I'm struggling to do anything with the access token.

First off, am I right in that the only time that I can get the access token, is with using `.getRedirectResult()`?

I don't seem to be able to access it as part of the normal AuthState. Does that mean I'll need to store the accessToken in local storage? How do I keep track of when the accessToken needs to be refreshed? Not bothered about asking the user to login again, just need to refresh the accessToken.

I would have assumed that the AngularFireAuth would have taken care of all that for you and it would internally track the accessToken.